# Can't populate a jstree with ajax data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jstree

I'm using jstree 3.2.1 and am trying to populate it with json data returned from an ajax script.

I've tested the script that produces the json data by accessing the URL, and it's returning valid json:

```
[{"id":"5","name":"Sector","parent_id":null},
{"id":"6","name":"Location","parent_id":null},
{"id":"7","name":"Italy","parent_id":"6"},
{"id":"8","name":"Poland","parent_id":"6"}]
```

The call to the ajax script is based on [jsTree - Populate Tree Dynamically using AJAX/C#Web Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467491/jstree-populate-tree-dynamically-using-ajax-cweb-method). So I have:

```
  $('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
      check_callback: true,
    },
    "data": {
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajaxGetTree",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
         data.d;
         $(data).each(function () {
            return { "id": this.id };
         });
      }
   },

  });
```

When I load the page, no request is being made to `/ajaxGetTree` and therefore there is no data appearing in the tree.

I previously had it partially working (but cannot revert back to the file I was in, annoyingly). However in that instance it was making the request to `/ajaxGetTree` but then just showing "Loading..." with a spinner in the area where the tree is supposed to appear. The data didn't appear in the jstree.

Please can someone provide some guidance and if possible code that actually does this - i.e. populates a tree from an ajax source.

The [official documentation](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) on it is extremely poor.

Comment: Possible that you can reproduce this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxlTweek/amzqp0pf/)?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see who is triggering call to build the jstree and from where.

The approach is a bit different but it works for me.

https://everyething.com/Example-of-simple-jsTree-with-dynamic-JSON-data